# replace values in all columns of a table with oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to replace all the cells of a table that match a specific word. I wrote this query:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column_name=REPLACE(column_name
                          ,'string_to_be_replaced'
                          , 'string_replaced')
```

What will the procedure that will replace the values for all the columns of *table_name* not only one column as in the code above?

It is something that I will have to do it againg and again to update some tables.

Thanks

Comment: What is the question :) ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is some test data:

```
SQL> select * from t23;

        ID NAME                 JOB
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 JACK                 JANITOR
        20 JAN                  TUTOR
        30 MOHAN                JAZZ DANCER
        40 JOAN                 MECHANIC

SQL>
```

I want to replace all instances of 'JA' with 'MO'. This means I need to update NAME and JOB. Obviously I could write an UPDATE statement but I can also generate one using the magic of the data dictionary:

```
SQL> select column_name, data_type
  2  from user_tab_cols
  3  where table_name = 'T23';

COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_TYPE
------------------------------ ----------
ID                             NUMBER
NAME                           VARCHAR2
JOB                            VARCHAR2

SQL>
```

This seems like a one-off task, for which I need an anonymous PL/SQL block rather than a permanent procedure. So here is a script, saved as `gen_upd_stmt.sql`.

```
declare
    stmt varchar2(32767);
    target_string varchar2(20) := 'JA';
    replace_string varchar2(20) := 'MO';
begin
    stmt := 'update t23 set ';
    for lrec in ( select column_name
                          , row_number() over (order by column_id) as id
                 from user_tab_cols
                  where table_name = 'T23'
                  and data_type = 'VARCHAR2'
                 )
    loop
        if lrec.id > 1 then 
           stmt := stmt || ',';
        end if;
        stmt := stmt || lrec.column_name || '=replace('
                     || lrec.column_name || ', ''' || target_string
                     || ''',''' || replace_string 
                     || ''')';
    end loop;
    --  uncomment for debugging
    --  dbms_output.put_line(stmt);
    execute immediate stmt;
    dbms_output.put_line('rows updated = '|| to_char(sql%rowcount));
end;
/
```

Note that generating dynamic SQL is a gnarly process, because syntax errors are thrown at run time rather than compile time. Escaping quotes can be particularly pestilential. It's a good idea to display the generated statement to make debugging easier.

Also, I restricted the targeted columns to those with the correct datatype. This isn't strictly necessary, as `replace()` will handle type casting for us (in most cases). But it's more efficient with big tables to exclude columns we know won't match.

Anyway, let's roll!

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> @gen_upd_stmt
rows updated = 4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

As expected all four rows are updated but not all are changed:

```
SQL> select * from t23;

        ID NAME                 JOB
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 MOCK                 MONITOR
        20 MON                  TUTOR
        30 MOHAN                MOZZ DANCER
        40 JOAN                 MECHANIC

SQL>
```

For completeness the generated statement was this:

```
update t23 set NAME=replace(NAME, 'JA','MO'),JOB=replace(JOB, 'JA','MO')
```

With a larger table or more complicated requirement I would probably introduce line breaks with `chr(13)||chr(10)` to make the generated code more readable (for debugging).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Rest update it as per your requirement.

```
DECLARE

   L_statement VARCHAR2(4000) := 'UPDATE :table_name SET ';

   CURSOR c_get_cols IS
   SELECT column_name
     FROM dba_tab_cols
    WHERE table_name = :table_name;

   TYPE Cur_tab IS TABLE OF c_get_cols%ROWTYPE;
   L_tab Cur_tab;

BEGIN

   OPEN c_get_cols;
   FETCH C_get_cols INTO L_tab;
   CLOSE C_get_cols;

   FOR i IN 1..L_tab.COUNT
   LOOP
      L_statement := L_statement || L_tab(i).column_name || ' = REPLACE(column_name, :string_to_be_replaced, :string_replaced)';
      IF i != L_tab.COUNT
      THEN
         L_statement := L_statement || ',';
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_statement;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it using cursor: (replace owner and table_name with respective values)

```
DECLARE 
 COL_NAME ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE;
  string_to_be_replaced VARCHAR2(20) ;
  string_replaced VARCHAR2 (20) ; 
  exc_invalid_id EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(exc_invalid_id, -904);
  CURSOR c1 IS
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE owner=<owner_name> AND TABLE_NAME=<table_name> ;
  BEGIN
  string_to_be_replaced :='';
   string_replaced :='';
  OPEN C1;
  LOOP 
  FETCH C1 INTO COL_NAME ;
  EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
  EXECUTE immediate('UPDATE <owner_name>.<table_name> SET '||col_name||'=REPLACE('||col_name||','''||string_to_be_replaced||''','''||string_replaced||''')');    
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C1;
  END;
```